# mysqli_fetch_array isn't working in php 7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This code for some reason isn't compatible with PHP 7

```
function sitaData()
{
    global $sitetitle_en,$sitetitle_ar,$sitekeywords,$sitedescription,$maintenance;
    mysqli_query("set names utf8");
    $query="select * from sitedata";
    $res=mysqli_query($query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
    {
        $record=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        $sitetitle_en=$record['sitetitle_en'];
        $sitetitle_ar=$record['sitetitle_ar'];
        $sitekeywords=$record['sitekeywords'];
        $sitedescription=$record['sitedescription'];
        $maintenance=$record['maintenance'];
    }

}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Read please [mcve] and explain what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Are you [mysqli_connect](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)ed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was probably converted from `mysql_*()` functions to `mysqli_*()` functions. The main difference between the two is that you have to explicitly pass mysqli connection identifier (the result of `mysqli_connect()`) to each `mysqli_query()` call. So at first you need to establish a connection (either in the function `sitaData()` or somewhere else and pass it to the function as parameter), and then you'll need to add the connection as the first parameter of `mysqli_query()`.

E.g. `mysqli_query($connection, "set names utf8");`, `$res=mysqli_query($connection, $query);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn= mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database');     
function sitaData()
 {
global $sitetitle_en,$sitetitle_ar,$sitekeywords,$sitedescription,$maintenance;
mysqli_query($conn,"set names utf8");
$query="select * from sitedata";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
{
    $record=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $sitetitle_en=$record['sitetitle_en'];
    $sitetitle_ar=$record['sitetitle_ar'];
    $sitekeywords=$record['sitekeywords'];
    $sitedescription=$record['sitedescription'];
    $maintenance=$record['maintenance'];
}

}
```

try this.